# Postgres FTS Priority Field

Tags: postgresql

I am using Postgres FTS to search a field in a table. The only issue is for some reason the below issue is happening.

```
store=# select name from service where to_tsvector(name) @@ to_tsquery('find:*') = true;
     name     
--------------
 Finding Nora
(1 row)

store=# select name from service where to_tsvector(name) @@ to_tsquery('findi:*') = true;
 name 
------
(0 rows)

store=# select name from service where to_tsvector(name) @@ to_tsquery('findi:*') = true;
```

How come when searching using the query findi:*,the result doesnt show?

Answer (score 1):

In my PG 12.2 with default text search configuration I have:

```
# select to_tsvector('Finding Nora');
    to_tsvector    
-------------------
 'find':1 'nora':2
(1 row)

# select to_tsquery('findi:*');
 to_tsquery 
------------
 'findi':*
(1 row)
```

I understand that because there is no lexeme `findi` in the default dictionary, the query does not find any match.